# Project Euler 4 - Largest palindrome product

Tags: java, programming-challenge

I submitted a solution to Project Euler 4 exercise: Largest palindrome product in Java. The content of following exercise:

> A palindromic number reads the same both ways. The largest palindrome
>   made from the product of two 2-digit numbers is 9009 = 91 × 99.
>
> Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit
>   numbers.

I wrote a method called isPalindrome that checks is reversing of string the same as output string. I have to obviously convert int to String to check is given number is palindrome. I created palindromes list and I loop for all possible three-digits numbers that would be multiplied and I check are these products palindromes. If yes, then I add it product to list. Next, I select only maximum palindrome from list and I print it to console.

**Main.java:**

```
package pl.hubot.projecteuler.problem4;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> palindromes = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
            for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
                if (isPalindrome(Integer.toString(i * j)))
                    palindromes.add(i * j);
            }
        }
        System.out.print(Collections.max(palindromes));
    }

    private static boolean isPalindrome(String str) {
        return str.equals(new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### We don't need a `List`

> ```
>         List<Integer> palindromes = new ArrayList<>();
> ```

This could be just

```
        int largest = -1;
```

As we just need to determine the largest one.

> ```
>         System.out.print(Collections.max(palindromes));
> ```

This just becomes

```
        System.out.print(largest);
```

#### Work down, not up

> ```
>         for (int i = 100; i <= 999; i++) {
>             for (int j = 100; j <= 999; j++) {
> ```

This does more work than necessary.  Instead, consider

```
        for (int i = 999; i >= 100; i--) {
            for (int j = i; j >= 100; j--) {
```

You want to find the maximum.  So start with the largest possible candidate and work your way down.

Also, you don't have to check \$999\cdot 998\$ and \$998\cdot 999\$.  It's enough to test one.  So we can start `j` as `i`.

There will be more that we can do later.

#### Convert after calling `isPalindrome`

> ```
>                 if (isPalindrome(Integer.toString(i * j)))
>                     palindromes.add(i * j);
> ```

Consider

```
                int product = i * j;
                if (product <= largest) {
                    break;
                }

                if (isPalindrome(product)) {
                    largest = product;
                }
```

If `product` is smaller than the `largest` palindrome found so far, we don't need to check these values anymore.  Also, we only update `largest` if `product` is larger.  So we don't need to do the `Collections.max` after.

We don't repeatedly calculate the same product (compiler probably fixes that for you anyway, but I find this easier to follow).

You said

> I have to obviously convert int to String to check is given number is palindrome.

But it is not obvious to me that we have to convert to a `String` to check if it is a palindrome.  That's a conceptually simple way, but we could do it more efficiently with math.  And this way, we can drop in a [math-based replacement](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/134126/71574) without altering this method.

And to fix the mismatched parameters without using a replacement, we could just write

```
    private static boolean isPalindrome(int candidate) {
        return isPalindrome(Integer.toString(candidate));
    }
```

And as I said, we can replace that method with a more efficient one without changing the caller.

Comment: you've said what i wanted to say and have done it better too! i bookmarked this question to take care of it later. i wonder how it would turn out if i implemented a TDD  approach? would be interesting to look at.